# Why does anyone use an encoding other than UTF-8?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

I want to know why any developer would need to use an encoding other than UTF-8.

Comment: Do you mean, compared to UTF-16, or compared to legacy non-Unicode encodings?

Comment: Related to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40063/should-character-encodings-besides-utf-8-and-maybe-utf-16-utf-32-be-deprecated

Answer (score 28):

Wikipedia lists advantages and disadvantages of UTF-8 as compared to a variety of other encodings:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages_and_disadvantages

The most important disadvantages are IMHO that UTF-8 might use significantly **more space especially in Asian languages** such as Chinese, Japanese or Hindi and that **not all code points have the same size** which makes measurements more difficult and many string operations such as search inefficient.

Comment: Not all code points have the same size in UTF-16.

Comment: But there are other encodings where this is the case such as UCS-2, ASCII, etc.

Comment: @0xA3: UCS-2 is an evil **obsolete** abortion of a character set. If you want to use a fixed-size character encoding, your only choice is UTF-32 (which is rarely used).

Comment: One of the interesting points made by the "UTF-8 Everywhere Manifesto" (http://www.utf8everywhere.org/) is that having all code points be the same size is not nearly as useful as it sounds. Some code points like diacritics aren't characters by themselves, because they combine with adjacent characters. There are also many non-printable code points like the byte-order-mark that don't count as characters at all. So many operations that you'd *think* would be more convenient with easily indexable code points (like column measurements) aren't actually that simple.

Answer (score 13):

Well, some do it because their tools are archaic or flawed. Some do it because they don't see a need to support anything other than ASCII. Some do it because they don't know any better.

Those are the usual excuses for not using Unicode.

As for not using UTF-8 specifically there are different reasons. Some systems, like Windows<sup>1</sup> (and stemming from that, .NET) and Java came to be in a time where Unicode was a strict 16-bit code. Therefore, there was really only one encoding: UCS-2, encoding code points directly as 16-bit words.

Later Unicode was expanded to 21 bits because 65536 code points weren't enough anymore. This caused encodings such as UTF-32 and UTF-16 to appear. For systems previously working with UCS-2 the transition to UTF-16 was the easiest and most sensible choice. Windows did that transition back in Ye Olde Days of Windows 2000.

So while I think that nearly all application nowadays should support *Unicode* I don't think it is entirely necessary for them to specifically use UTF-8. There are historic reasons for that and no real benefit in converting existing systems from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

---

<sup>1</sup> NT.

Comment: Windows still did not fully transitioned to UTF-16. Try writing non-BMP characters to the console, for example...

Answer (score 9):

In UTF-8 code points between `0800` and `FFFF` take up three bytes in UTF-8 but only two in UTF-16. See the [wikipedia comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Compared_to_UTF-16) for more details, but basically if text heavily uses code points in this range (say, if it's Chinese), UTF-8 files will be larger than UTF-16 files with the same content.

Comment: For Chinese in China mainland, many people might consider GB18030 as Unicode encoding before UTF-16.

Answer (score 7):

UTF-8 is very efficient at encoding plain English text (same as ASCII). If your user base is likely to be mostly, say, Chinese, you will be much better off using UTF-16.

For more information, see [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: I found the linked blog entry from Joel very informative. Thanks!

Comment: The link to Joel’s crap about Unicode is worth a downvote. It advocates UCS-2, UTF-7 and highlights sentences like “This is not, actually, correct.” and doesn’t get the facts straight (e.g. the history about Unicode).

Answer (score 6):

Because outside the English-speaking world, people have been using various encodings that predate Unicode and are tailored for their respective languages for decades. These language-specific encodings have become ingrained everywhere and are pretty much a standard. If you want to have any hope of interfacing with legacy systems, you have to use them, so all systems have to support them and usually use them as default even if they by now support UTF-8 as well. There may even be multiple legacy encodings traditionally used for different purposes.

Examples:

- [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) in western Europe - actually outdated there as well, as you need [ISO-8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) for the Euro sign
- [ISO-2022-JP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022) in Japan for emails, [Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) for websites
- [Big5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5) in Taiwan
- [GB2312](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312) in China

The last two examples show that encodings can even be a political issue.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes they are restricted due to historical/unsupported reasons (I'm developing on Windows using Zend Studio on a Samba share on a Linux box: and something in that mix means I keep reverting to Cp1512 instead of UTF8).

Sometimes you don't need to use UTF-8 (for example when storing a md5 hash in a database: you only need the hexadecimal range 0-9 A-F: why make it a UTF-8 field, which will take at least a byte extra storage instead of normal ASCII).

Sometimes it's just laziness learning the UTF-8 functions for a particular language.

Comment: Why would the UTF8 representation of hex digits occupy more storage than the ASCII representation?  The byte values are the same in the two encodings.

Comment: UTF-8 does not take more bytes than ASCII for encoding ASCII. Why do you think it needs an extra byte?

Comment: Ok, perhaps I should have qualified it a bit more. I've seen some implementations [if I recall correctly, it *might* have been Oracle] store a byte order marker (BOM) for all UTF8 data fields: some implementations don't use it unless the data is non-ASCII, some don't use it unless the BOM differs from the "default".

Comment: @Richy C: Cp1512??? Do you mean cp1251? cp1252?

Comment: Yep John, seems I made a typo: I meant Cp1252 instead Cp1512. D'uh! Principle is the same though ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, most developers still don't know the difference between latin-1, utf-8, unicode and ascii and just shy away when the important questions are asked. - In the end, rely on system defaults, which are risky.

Answer (score 5):

Because they do not know better.
The only valid criticism to utf-8 is that encodings for common Asian languages are oversized from other encodings.
UTF-8 is superior because

- It is ASCII compatible. Most known and tried string operations do not need adaptation.

  It is Unicode. Anything that isn't Unicode shouldn't even be considered in this day and age. If you have important data in encoding X, spend two minutes on Google and write a conversion function. Even if you have to interface with sourceless legacy app Z, you can run your communications through a pipe so that your logic stays in the 21st century.

  UTF-16 isn't fixed length either and assuming it is like many do, will only cause terrible bugs.

  Additionally Unicode is very complex and it is almost certain than any fixed-size algorithm adapted from ASCII will yield bad results even in UTF-32.

Say you have this UTF-16 string.

```
[0][1][2][F|3] [4] [5]
```

And you want to insert a character with code 8 between [3] and [4]
you would do insert(5,8)

If you don't check for characters outside BMP(serially as in UTF-8 as you cannot know how many double sized characters you have) you get:

```
[0][1][2][F|8][3][4][5]
```

Two new garbage characters. So much for your fixed size encoding.
You can of course disallow such characters altogether, but then when your code interfaces with the real world, you might find your program saves the profile for this user who lives in rm -Rf / in .profile instead of [Classical Chinese Proverb].profile.

Or just an angry user that cannot write his thesis on Classical Chinese Proverbs with your software.

Answer (score 4):

One legitimate reason is when you need to deal with legacy documents, software or hardware that are not Unicode compatible.

Another legitimate reason is that you need to use a programming language / libraries that do not support UTF8 / Unicode well ... or at all.

Other answers mention that UTF-16 is more compact than UTF-8 for Asian languages / characters.

And of course there are reasons like short-sightedness, ignorance, laziness ... and deadlines.

Comment: +1 another nice summary, and that real-world edge, ooh can't beat it.

Answer (score 3):

Its also worth remembering that in some circumstances (where a non-latin set of characters are needed) UTF-8 can actually bloat larger than the 16 bit Unicode encoding.  In those cases ucs-2 or utf-16 would be a better choice.

Comment: Besides, you should never use UCS2 if you can avoid it because it can only encode part of unicode (plane 0, BMP, the 0-FFFF range) and that may break your program in interesting ways.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons for using non-Unicode 8-bit character sets / encodings are all back compatibility of some kind, and/or inertia. For that matter, the most frequent reasons for using UTF-8 are compatibility with standards like XML that mandate or prefer UTF-8.

Differences in the number of bytes you think text will take up in different encodings, especially in storage, are mostly theoretical. In real world situations, compatibility requirements are more important. If compression is used, the size differences go away anyway. Even if compression is not used, total text size is hard to predict and is rarely a deciding factor.

When converting legacy code that used non-Unicode 8-bit encodings, using UTF-16 can be a tool for making sure all code has been converted, because mismatches can be caught as compile-time type errors. Many languages, runtimes and libraries like Javascript, JVM, .NET, ICU use 16-bit strings and UTF-16, even though storage and Internet protocols are usually 8-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the subject, when using MySQL, as if it wasn't complex enough, you get the option the choose which kind of UTF-8 collation you want to use. So what would you use?

`UTF-8 general ci`
or
`UTF-8 unicode ci`?

(I tend to use the UTF-8 variant that is used for the database connection)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine all files to consider are in GB2312 (China mainland standard). Then you might choose GB18030 as Unicode encoding instead. They are compatible the same way as all ASCII is UTF-8. That is useful in China mainland!

You might decide even quicker when you find out that both mentioned GB-standards are required in your IT-product by law (as far as I have heard), if you want to ship in China (mainland).

Another upside is that GB2312, and as such GB18030 as well, are also ASCII compatible.

It is algorithmically not so robust, though. – So if you have no political reasons or any GB2312 legacy, it makes no sense to use it. But if you do, here you got your answer.

Comment: Do you have a source for this "legal requirement"? That sounds interesting, but a quick search reveals nothing about it.

Comment: Searching for “mandatory” in the [GB18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030) and related Wikipedia articles should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Because you sometimes want to operate easily on codepoints -- then you'd choose f.e. UCS-2 or UCS-4.

Comment: UCS-2 is limited to the BMP. Certainly not the smartest choice nowadays.

Comment: @Joey, not a problem if you know that every character in your string is in the BMP.  If you define it as UCS-2 then you know that every character is the same width (2 bytes) but if you define it as UTF-16 (even though the encoded bytes may be identical) you have to check for surrogate pairs.

Comment: @finn: I don't consider developer laziness a valid reason to impose arbitrary restrictions on users. Unicode hasn't been a 16-bit code for quite some time now; there is no reason to perpetuate invalid assumptions. By the same argument you can probably make ISO 8859 look beneficial but it's not.

Comment: @Joey, it's not about laziness.  If the source (e.g. a legacy database) is already limited to 8859-1 for example, you could convert it to UTF-8 (which you might want to do for consistency if the rest of your system uses UTF-8) but it's a trade-off because then you no longer have fixed-width characters.  If you leave it as 8859-1 or convert it to UCS-2 or UTF-32 you still have a fixed-width encoding.  This is *not* the case if you convert it to UTF-8, UTF-16, GB18030 etc.

Comment: (continued) This can be a pain (and require costly modifications) when using APIs that were originally designed for a fixed-width encoding (ASCII or UCS-2) and later "retrofitted" to treat the same arguments as UTF-8 or UTF-16.  I have seen this in some Java projects (Java has migrated from UCS-2 to UTF-16.)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode certainly is a good place to work from in most cases, but a developer should be familiar with many different types of character encoding.  Certainly ASCII might be used if the set of characters is limited.

What if you're a developer and receiving data from a source that doesn't send UTF-8?  There could be lots of interface issues if you don't understand your input.

[Joel's article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on the must-knows for character encoding is good and worth reading.

Comment: Joel’s article is not worth reading. See my other comment around here.

Answer (score 0):

Many APIs require other Unicode encodings - mostly UTF-16. For instance, Java, .NET, Win32.

Comment: .NET use UTF-8 as default encoding.

Comment: @awe: not sure what you mean by "default encoding", but I can assure you that the .NET String class internally stores text as UTF-16.

Comment: OK - you are right that [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Characters) is internally UTF-16. What I based this on is that reading from file is default read using UTF-8 encoding (see  [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) ).

Comment: These differences are explained a bit closer in  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200063/why-does-anyone-use-an-encoding-other-than-utf-8/2470079#2470079) answer by **Joseph Boyle**.

Answer (score 0):

At my previous employer we used iso-8859-1 for some of our ASP pages to match the collation of our SQL Server, which as you can guess was not Unicode. I wanted to change the collation, but the manager said to wait till we upgrade our SQL Server to do it. Needless to say it never happened - I haven't been with them for a little over a year now, so I don't know if they finally did it.