# Point of other encoding rather than UTF-8

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8

I have been working with `String` in various programming language for a long time, and I haven't come across a situation where I need to use any other encoding except `UTF-8`

The question might feel like opinion based, but I don't understand why other encoding should be available.

wouldn't it just make everyone's life (especially programmers) easier to just have one single standard?

I take `Java` as an example:

A Set of currently available encoding for Java can be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088473/why-are-there-different-encoding-types. Some encodings may be more efficient for certain types of data, interacting with legacy applications, may be some reasons.

Comment: Reasons to use different encoding => legacy systems or hardware (*UTF-8* was published in 1993) and performance (*UTF-16* is usually what is stored in memory to make operations based on character offset more effective).

Comment: Please also consider interactions with legacy programs. While I agree UTF-8 should be the default in most cases, sometimes you need to be able to select another encoding (or would you rather re-develop an encoding conversion algorithm each time?).

Answer (score 1):

[UTF-8: Advantages and disadvantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages%5Fand%5Fdisadvantages)

The typical argument is:

> Asian languages have many more characters and would require oversized
>   encoding for their languages.

However, the Pros outweigh the cons in my opinion:

1. UTF-8, in general is much more powerful due to is compatibility with ASCII
2. The fact that it is Unicode
3. Other UTF-16/32 are not fixed-length
4. Others that are not unicode are extremely complex

I would take a gander over here: [Why don't people use other encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200063/why-does-anyone-use-an-encoding-other-than-utf-8).

Comment: a very good point, each encoding have pros and cons. but as you said pros out weight the cons. that's exactly my point

Comment: UTF-8 is not fixed-length, any more than UTF-16 or UTF-32 are.  UTF-8 uses 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes per Unicode codepoint, depending on its value. UTF-16 uses either 2 or 4 bytes per codepoint, depending on its value.  UTF-32 always uses 4 bytes per codepoint, at least. But in all three cases, more than one codepoint may be required to represent any given glyph that the user actually sees.  Thus all three encodings are effectively variable-length.

Answer (score 1):

String in java are internally represented as UTF-16, when you build a String you don't have to tell what encoding to use as internal representation (but you have to pass the encoding if you are building a String from an array of bytes).

The link you provided shows the Encoding available for read and write operations; if you want to read correctly a text file encoded in ISO-8859-1 on a platform where the default encoding is UTF-8 you must specify the correct encoding and your language (java in this case) must be able to automatically convert from one encoded form to another.

Java manage a lot of encodings and the convertion from one to another, but internally it represents Strings as UTF-16, but you don't have to worry about that; you only must specifiy the encoding when transforming a String to a sequence of bytes, or vice versa.